# Internal Server Error when specifying maxResults parameter greater than 7 - Google YouTube Data API v3

Tags: youtube-api, google-api, youtube-data-api

I am getting a "500 - Internal Server Error" with no detail message in response when I make a request to the playlists section of the YouTube data api and I specify a maxResults parameter greater than 7.

A maxResults value 7 or below seems to work but not values greater than 7.  The documentation states the maxResults parameter can be a value 0-50.

"The maxResults parameter specifies the maximum number of items that should be returned in the result set. Acceptable values are 0 to 50, inclusive. The default value is 5."

Below is the call I am making to the API:

`<cfhttp method="get" url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists">
      <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="key" value="MYKEY" />
      <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="part" value="id,snippet" />
      <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="channelId" value="CHANNELID" />
      <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="maxResults" value="50" />
</cfhttp>`

I also get the error even when using their built in API Explorer tool on the page below.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I also started seeing this issue approximately 37 hours ago. Through some experimentation right now, I tracked down the issue to an empty playlist that the API seems to choke on. Technically, it used to have videos but they've all been deleted. When I deleted that empty playlist the API worked again. Is the 8th playlist in your user's account an empty playlist?

I can confirm that this error was not being thrown 7 days ago, even though I still had such an empty playlist on my account. Something must have been pushed out from youtube's side that has broken this special case.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO!

I know you're a new user, and don't have the rep to add comments yet - but I just wanted to flag that when you do have sufficient reputation, this probably should be a comment, not an answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am having a similar experience in that it had been working fine and then just stopped working 48 hours ago.  I checked the playlists on the channel and there wasn't an empty one or any that was different than the others.